# angular ng-repeat is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to run a small example but it is not working.
the html.

```
<body ng-app="angello">
<div ng-contoller="mainController">
  <div class="span4 sidebar-content">
    <h2> stories </h2>
      <div ng-repeat="story in stories">
        <h4> {{ story.title }} </h4>
        <p> {{ story.description }} </p>
      </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

the script code is:

```
angular.module('angello',[])
         .controller('mainController', function( $scope ) {
      $scope.stories = [
        {title:'Story 00', description:'Description pending.'},
        {title:'Story 01', description:'Description pending.'},
        {title:'Story 02', description:'Description pending.'},
        {title:'Story 03', description:'Description pending.'},
        {title:'Story 04', description:'Description pending.'},
        {title:'Story 05', description:'Description pending.'}];
  });
```

expected is that the stories are listed but there is only the 
{{ story.title }}
{{ story.description }}
tags. What is the Problem? why are the stories not listed?

the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tire0011/gU7Qx/

Comment: In the "Frameworks & Extensions" section you have selected "onLoad". That's too late because angular already runs then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your HTML, you misspelled `ng-controller`. You're missing an `r`. Of course, also, close the `body` tag.

After fixing your `ng-controller`, to make your code work in jsFiddle, you also have to change `onLoad` on `Frameworks & Extensions` to `No-wrap - in <head>` as @zeroFlagL mentioned.

Comment: @StarsSky `ng-contoller` is correct? Well, it does sound cool, so I guess we could consider it correct.

Comment: even fixing the tag, the problem persist. Correct answer is in the comment of zeroflagL

Comment: @KhanhTO yes but you changed the onload action!

Comment: @StarsSky the main problem with the code is the typo. The onDomReady, onload, in <head>, etc, is jsFiddle related. It's not a problem with the code. Why did you delete your comment after I replied to it? Could you at least remove the down-vote then?

Comment: Up for you! Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

changing the misspelled controller

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="span4 sidebar-content">
```

and putting the javascript in head, (choosing option No wrap in ) seems to be working.